# Problem regarding a trapezoid with a given properties and the intersection point of the lines $DE$ and $BG$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Let $ABCD$ be a trapezoid s. t. $AB\parallel DC,\ |AB|=2|DC|$ and $AD\perp BD$. Let $P$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB},\ E, F, G$ be the intersection points of $AD\ \&\ BC,\ PC\ \&\ BD$ and $EF\ \&\ DC$ respectively.
>
> Prove that $BG$ is passing through the midpoint of $\overline{DE}$.

---

**My attempt:**

$\overline{DC}$ is the midsegment of $\triangle ABE$.

$|AB|=2|DC|\implies |AP|=|PB|=|DC|$, so quadrilaterals $APCD, PBCD$ and $PCED$ are parallelograms.
$AD\perp BD\ \land AD\parallel PC\implies\ BD\perp PC$ so, $PBCD$ is a rhombus and $\triangle APD,\triangle PBC,\triangle DCE$ and $\triangle ABE$ are isosceles.

At first glance, I thought I should expand the triangles to get another parallelogram, e.g., a parallelogram with the diagonals $\overline{DC}$ and $\overline{BH}$, where $H$ is the intersection point of $PD$ and $BG$, but that is a bit circular.

Then I thought of using the *intercept theorem*, but I can't apply it directly to the segment $\overline{DE}$.

Since I have to prove $BG$ bisects the segment $\overline{DE}$ I shouldn't assume a median of $\triangle BCD$ belongs to the line $BG$.

Picture:

[image]

---

May I ask for advice on how to solve this task?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $G$ is the centroid of $BDE$.

---

Note: I didn't use $BD \perp AD$, so I might have made a mistake.

Comment: It appears that the perpendicular condition can actually be dropped.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow forgot to use the fact $\triangle BCF\sim\triangle  BED$.